# How to loop in the opposite order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner programmer.  Here is my code:

```
n = int(input())
from math import*
for i in range(n):
    print(n, "\t", log10(n))
    i = i + 1
    n = n - 1
```

Its output is:

```
10   1.0
9    0.9542425094393249
8    0.9030899869919435
7    0.8450980400142568    
6    0.7781512503836436
5    0.6989700043360189    
4    0.6020599913279624
3    0.47712125471966244
2    0.3010299956639812
1    0.0
```

I want it to be:

```
1    0.0
2    0.3010299956639812
3    0.47712125471966244
4    0.6020599913279624
5    0.6989700043360189
.
.
.
9    0.9542425094393249
10   1.0
```

Comment: `for i in range(n,0,-1):
    print i` if you want to go backwards. `range(0,n,1)` to go forwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you don't need to increment `i`, because it is the loop variable and is being set to each of 0 to 9 in turn.

Then your loop is printing `n` first. It starts at 10, and you subtract one from it each time, so you are getting the values in descending order. Try this:

```
for i in range(n):
    print i+1, "\t", log10(i+1)
```

Comment: n=int(input())
while n!=0:
    from math import*
    print (n,"\t",log10(n))
    n=n-1

Comment: You can also do `range(1, n+1)` to iterate from 1 through n. Doesn't save much here, but a bit clearer to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `i` as you variable element in the loop:

```
n=int(input())
import math

for i in range(1,n+1):
    print(i,"\t",math.log10(i))
```

You can do this in one line like so:

```
print('\n'.join('{}\t{}'.format(i,math.log10(i)) for i in range(1,n+1)))
```

Lastly, it is not a great idea to get used to doing `from math import *`. Using `*` brings all the items in the imported module into the same namespace. Any similar object or function names in the module will overwrite other functions/objects with the same name.